# CDK Drag and Drop Lag

Tags: angular, typescript, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk

I've been tasked with optimizing a drag and drop resource calendar. We are using Angular's CDK Drag and Drop, but there are performance issues, particularly with the drop event. I'm not really familiar with TypeScript/JavaScript + Angular, so I am having some trouble. I think that whenever the client is dragging something, too many requests are being made. It seems to be working fine whenever the mouse is not hovered  over the drop event.

You can see an example of what my problem is here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUoFl.gif

TypeScript

```
dropIntoShipmentsTable(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>, hour, driver) {
    if (event.item.data != null) {
      // Store data about post request -> Place of dropped data
      let updateDriver;
      // If moving shipment from cell to cell
      if (event.previousContainer.id === "shipmentCell") {
        updateDriver = {
          DriverId: driver,
          id: event.item.data.id,
          TimeFrom: this.moment(hour).format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm"),
          userId: this.user.id().toString(),
        };
      } else {
        // If dropping from QUE
        updateDriver = {
          DriverId: driver,
          containerId:
            event.previousContainer.id === "containersQueList"
              ? event.item.data.id
              : null,
          chassisId:
            event.previousContainer.id === "chassisQueList"
              ? event.item.data.id
              : null,
          id:
            event.previousContainer.id === "shipmentsQueList" ||
            event.previousContainer.id === "prepullsQueList" ||
            event.previousContainer.id === "stagingsQueList"
              ? event.item.data.id
              : null,
          TimeFrom: this.moment(hour).format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm"),
          userId: this.user.id().toString(),
          isContainer: event.item.data.isContainer,
        };
      }
      this.subs.sink = this.api
        .assignShipmentToDriver(updateDriver)
        .subscribe(() => {
          if (this.filterParams.active) {
            this.initDay(this.filterParams);
          } else {
            this.initDay(this.params);
          }
          this.cdr.detectChanges();
        });
    }
  }
```

HTML

The 'shipments-assigned' div is the wrapper for the calendar, working hours is the y-axis column.

````
   <div class="working-hours">
      <div class="column-row-name">
         <p>
            Drivers <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i> <br />
            Hours <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
         </p>
      </div>
      <div
         *ngFor="let hour of workingHours; trackBy: trackByHour"
         class="hour"
         draggable="true"
         >
         {{ hour | date: 'shortTime' }}
      </div>
   </div>
   <div
      *ngIf="drivers$ | async as drivers; else loader"
      class="driver-droplist-wrapper"
      >
      <div
         *ngFor="let driver of drivers; trackBy: trackByDriver"
         class="driver-column driver-droplist"
         >
         <div
            [matTooltip]="driver.driver"
            class="column-info"
            draggable="true"
            >
            {{ driver.driverName | slice: 0:21 }}
         </div>
         <div class="working-hours-droparea">
            <div
            (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
            *ngFor="let hour of workingHours"
            [ngStyle]="
            hour.toString() >= hoursToMs(driver.startTime) &&
            hour.toString() <= hoursToMs(driver.endTime) && {
            background: 'RGBA(0,114,0,0.37)'
            }
            "
            cdkDropList
            class="hour-droparea"
            id="shipmentCell"
            >
            <ng-container *ngFor="let shipment of driver.items">
               <span
               (contextmenu)="onRightClick($event, shipment, driver)"
               *ngIf="hour.toString() === hoursToMs(shipment.timeFrom)"
               [cdkDragData]="shipment"
               [cdkDragDisabled]="shipment.isReturn"
               [ngClass]="'shipment-duration-' + shipment.duration"
               [style.background]="shipment.colorCode"
               cdkDrag
               draggable="true"
               >
               <small>{{ shipment.originDestination }}</small>
               <br />
               <small class="container"
                  ><strong>{{ shipment.container }}</strong></small
                  >
               <br />
               <small>{{ shipment.chassisPool }}</small>
               <!-- an hidden div is created to set the position of appearance of the menu-->
               <div
               #rightClickMenuTrigger
               [matMenuTriggerFor]="shipmentRightClick"
               [style.left]="menuTopLeftPosition.x"
               [style.top]="menuTopLeftPosition.y"
               style="visibility: hidden; position: fixed"
               >
         </div>
         <!-- standard material menu for click on the folder -->
         <mat-menu #shipmentRightClick="matMenu">
         <ng-template let-item="item" matMenuContent>
         <span (click)="openConfirmationDialog()" mat-menu-item
            ><mat-icon class="text-danger">undo</mat-icon>Return
         empty container</span
            >
         <span (click)="getContainerDetails()" mat-menu-item
            ><mat-icon class="text-success">add</mat-icon>Assign
         container</span
            >
         <span
         (click)="setAsPrepull(true)"
         *ngIf="!shipment.prepull"
         mat-menu-item
         ><mat-icon class="text-warning"
            >horizontal_split</mat-icon
            >Set as prepull</span
            >
         <span
         (click)="setAsPrepull(false)"
         *ngIf="shipment.prepull"
         mat-menu-item
         ><mat-icon class="text-danger"
            >horizontal_split</mat-icon
            >Unset prepull</span
            >
         <span
         (click)="setAsStaging(true)"
         *ngIf="!shipment.staging"
         mat-menu-item
         ><mat-icon class="text-warning">segment</mat-icon
            ><span class="text-warning"
            >Set as staging</span
            ></span
            >
         <span
         (click)="setAsStaging(false)"
         *ngIf="shipment.staging"
         mat-menu-item
         ><mat-icon class="text-danger">segment</mat-icon>
         <span class="text-danger">Unset staging </span></span
            >
         <span (click)="setBobtail()" mat-menu-item
            ><mat-icon class="text-danger"
            >takeout_dining</mat-icon
            >
         <span class="text-success">Bobtail </span></span
            >
         <span (click)="setPin('in')" mat-menu-item
            ><mat-icon class="text-success">push_pin</mat-icon>
         <span class="text-success">Pin in </span></span
            >
         <span (click)="setPin('out')" mat-menu-item
            ><mat-icon class="text-warning">push_pin</mat-icon>
         <span class="text-warning">Pin out </span></span
            >
         <span (click)="createNewContainer()" mat-menu-item>
         <mat-icon class="example-tab-icon text-success"
            >widgets</mat-icon
            >
         <span class="text-success">Create new container</span>
         </span>
         <span (click)="createNewChassis()" mat-menu-item>
         <mat-icon class="example-tab-icon text-warning"
            >widgets</mat-icon
            >
         <span class="text-warning">Create new chassis</span>
         </span>
         <span (click)="checkInTime()" mat-menu-item>
         <mat-icon class="example-tab-icon text-success"
            >update</mat-icon
            >
         <span class="text-success">Check in time</span>
         </span>
         <span (click)="checkOutTime()" mat-menu-item>
         <mat-icon class="example-tab-icon text-danger"
            >restore</mat-icon
            >
         <span class="text-danger">Check out time</span>
         </span>
         </ng-template>
         </mat-menu>
         </span>
         </ng-container>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfZ9V.gif
````

Comment: The only `CDK` function you are using is `cdkDropListDropped` and not `cdkDragMoved` (which is triggered at every move of the mouse), so your lag won't come from here. My guess, is that `Angular change detection` is triggered at every mouse mouvement you do and something in your component/HTML is taking all the resource for refreshing the screen. You'll have to analyze the issue with `Performance` tab of your dev console and see which function is the culprit.